# Jquery open a popup and nest it into the clicked div

Tags: jquery, append, appendto

I want to open a popup and nest it into a div. I'm using **appendTo**. 
my popup has to be open inside the clicked div. **parent**?

then append some html.
what I'm missing?

fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/XeELs/151/

```
 if ($("#events .event").hasClass("selected")) {
            $('.popup-event').parent().appendTo($(".event"));
            $(this).fadeIn();
            $('.popup-event').append('<span class="close-popup-event" />'); 
        }else{
            $('.close-popup-event').fadeOut('');
       }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="event">
</div>



<aside class="popup-event">

</aside>
```

Comment: can you create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) for this example?

Comment: Show some markup, and clarify the question please as the wording makes your desired intent unclear.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/XeELs/141/

Comment: I want to open my popup which is a separated html into the clicked div

Comment: `if ($("#events .event").hasClass("selected")) {` doesn't work with your jsfiddle example

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/XeELs/149/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a9AHt/1/

I wrapped the whole thing in `<div id="events">` and changed the class to "selected" so the event would fire.

If you take out the `.parent()` in the `appendTo` clause then it'll put the right element in.

Also, to make it relative to where that `.event` div is, you'd want to references `$(this)` in the click event, so you don't accidentally get another div.

Finally, add `position:relative` to the `.event` div to make sure it's always in that element.

Answer (score 0):

Your first statement is backwards. Either change it to $(".event").appendTo($('.popup-event').parent()); or change appendTo to be append and it will work. Furthermore, verify that both of your jQuery object are not empty.

Answer (score 0):

You might try something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/mkprogramming/XeELs/150/

```
$('.event a').click(function() {
        $('.popup-event').appendTo($(this).parent());
        $('.popup-event').fadeIn();
        $('.popup-event').append('<span class="close-popup-event" />'); 
});​
```

I think the key part to notice is the `$(this).parent()`

Answer (score 0):

I think there are some mistakes in your code. First, I would say it would be better to use id instead of class for popup-event as (as far as I understand) it is unique.

Also, when you write

```
 $('.popup-event').parent().appendTo($(".event"));
```

you try to append the **parent** of your "popup-event" div to your "event" div.

What I would do (If I understand correctly) is this:

```
$("div.event").bind('click', function() {
 $("#popup-event").appendTo($(this));
});
```

assuming you've put an id on "popup-event" and you want it to appear inside the clicked div. If you want it to appear inside the parent of the clicked div, you would append to

```
$(this).parent()
```